# Copy directory in server to directory in local machine

Tags: terminal, command-line, ssh

My class requires for us to make the homework in a linux server, but i want to copy those files to my local machine. I've tried so far to to use the `cp` command but it doesn't seem to take my arguments. It always return with either the host `directory does not exist` or with the target `directory does not exist`.

My approach so far has been:

```
cp -R /chapter2 ~/Documents/Projects
```

Keep in mind that i'm connected to a remote server on `ssh`.

Comment: If you can SSH to the system, consider using rsync to bring the remote files to your local system (or SCP)

Comment: [How to copy a file from a remote server to a local machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-machine)

Comment: i checked the link but it still misses the part of my local machine getting a folder from the remote server. I tried using `rsync` but i kept getting an error saying that the directory does not exist.

Comment: Can you please add the commands you've tried and the errors you get to the question? It's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing which commands you are using ;-)

Comment: SCP uses SSH, so if that's not working, it's probably user error. Can you give us the command you're running and the error?

Comment: It's **very** unlikely that the folder */chapter2* exists on the remote machine. /chapter2 would mean that it's in the root of the remote volume (and probably a chapter1 and chapter 3 folder). I would expect it to be in a superior folder like lessons/file_management_linux/chapter1 ...chapter2 etc and the lessons folder somewhere in /shares/class1/. So the path on the remote host would be /shares/class1/lessons/file_management_linux/chapter2. And the command something like `scp username@remote:/shares/class1/lessons/file_management_linux/chapter2/file ~/Documents/Projects/chapter2/`

Comment: I tried `scp -r myusername@remote:/home/myusername/chapter2/*.c ~/Documents/Projects`                                                                                and got this output:                              `/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory
/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory
/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory
/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory
/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory
/home/myusername/Documents/Projects: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the help of @klanomath. It never occurred to me that the command is supposed to be executed without connection to the `host@IP:`. I just added `-r` and `/*file.` to the command to get all files in one instance.

```
scp -r host@IP:/home/username/chapter2/*.c ~/Documents/Projects
```